# How to accses The ID of CheckBox in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I want to, when I double click the card the dialog pop up. Then it is possible to create dynamic checkBoxes. When creating the checkBoxes it is possible to edit the text, of each CheckBoxes. The problem comes if I have eg. created 3 checkboxes and want to edit one of them, all the others checkboxes get the same name as the one I want to edit. You can see the problem in the image below:

[image]

Jquery:

```
function addCheckbox(name, status) {
        status = status || false;

        var container = $('#divboxs');
        var inputs = container.find('input');
        var id = inputs.length + 1;
        var data = {
            status: status,
            name: name
        };

        var div = $('<div />', { class: 'allcheckbox' });
        $('<input />', {
            type: 'checkbox',
            id: 'cb' + id,
            value: name
        }).prop('checked', status).on('change', function () {
            data.status = $(this).prop('checked');
        }).appendTo(div); /* set checkbox status and monitor changes */

        $('<label />', {
            'for': 'cb' + id,
            text: name
        }).appendTo(div);

        var $editCheckBox = $('<p />', {
            class: 'editCheckBox',
            text: 'Edit'
        }).appendTo(div);

        div.appendTo(container);

        container.data('checkboxes').push(data);
    }

        $('#divboxs').on('click', '.editCheckBox', function () {
        var text = $(this).parents(".allcheckbox").find("label").text();
        var input = $('<input id="attribute" value="' + text + '" />')
        $('.allcheckbox').text('').append(input);
        input.select();

        input.blur(function () {
            var text = $('#attribute').val();
            $('#attribute').parent().text(text);
            $('#attribute').remove();
        });
    });    

});
```

I think this is the part of the code that gives me problems: 
`var input = $('<input id="attribute" value="' + text + '" />')`

I think I should use the ID of CheckBox: `id: 'cb' + id`, instead of `id="attribute"`. How to insert the id of checkBox at this place ?

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/62QY8/120/)

Comment: _I think I should use the ID of CheckBox: id: 'cb' + id._ **Yes**, you should because IDs must be **unique**

Comment: You would do that the same way you've done the `value` attribute for that element...

Comment: How? Please provide some code. I tried by myself, but not succeeded. Therefore I ask you.

Comment: I tried this var input = $('<input id="' + 'cb'+ id + '" value="' + text + '" />'). But seems to not work.

Comment: @AdiT are you trying to edit one input at a time?

Comment: @marcjae Yes this is my intention.

Comment: @AdiT That looks fine as far as the string concatenation is concerned. I think though that `id` isn't defined at that point. Where is that variable coming from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. So there are a few issues with your code.

The first being. You append the newly created input to all "allcheckbox" class elements

```
$('.allcheckbox').text('').append(input);
```

The second issue, is in that same line you are emptying that entire DIV. Which will create issues once you want to update the input and label with the new value.

So rather hide any elements you would not want to display, once the blur event is called, remove the new input, update the values then show the elements you previously hide.

Find an updated fiddle below:
http://jsfiddle.net/62QY8/122/

Also, on a bit of a side note. "class" is a JavaScript reserved word. So rather use "classname". ie.

```
    var $editCheckBox = $('<p />', {
        classname: 'editCheckBox',
        text: 'Edit'
    }).appendTo(div);
```

Comment: I have a problem when I create one checkbox and name it eg. "Hallo". Then I want to edit it, and name it "Hallo World", then save the data via Button "Get value". When I open the same card the checkBox is still named "Hallo", and not "Hallo World". Hmm Why that? Can you please help ? I have a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/62QY8/124/

Comment: To accomplish what you want to do, you need to update the input objects' name property. I've done so by adding the line into the on change event listener then trigger the event once the value has been updated. I've updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/62QY8/133/

Comment: You just add this line: element.children('input').change();

Comment: As well as line 72. data.name = $(this).val();

Comment: Hi again. I have a last question to you, and thank you for helping me. I added a commentbox to the fiddel. But I have stil the same problem as I described above. When I create one comment and name it eg. "Hallo". Then I want to edit it, and name it "Hallo World", then save the data via Button "Get value". When I open the same card the comment is still named "Hallo", and not "Hallo World". I tried to implement this line on label element: .on('change', function () {            
            data1.commentString = $(this).val();
        }).appendTo(div); But not working. Can you please help me?

Comment: I've updated my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/62QY8/137/. The new code goes on from line 122.

Comment: I would suggest posting a new question

Comment: Okay. You are maybe not able to solve this problem ?

Comment: No its not that, its that the question is not within scope of the original question

Comment: Should I ask the question in the same scope, or post a new question in a new scope?

Comment: I think post a new question

Answer (score 1):

I am not so sure what exactly is being done here.
But if the idea is to edit on checkbox at a time then please chek the following fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/62QY8/121/

```
    $(function () {
// Click function to add a card
var $div = $('<div />').addClass('sortable-div');

var cnt = 0,
    $currentTarget;
$('#AddCardBtn').click(function () {
    var $newDiv = $div.clone(true);
    cnt++;
    $newDiv.prop("id", "div" + cnt);

    $newDiv.data('checkboxes', []);

    $('#userAddedCard').append($newDiv);
    //      alert($('#userAddedCard').find("div.sortable-div").length);        
});

// Double click to open Modal Dialog Window
$('#userAddedCard').dblclick(function (e) {
    $currentTarget = $(e.target);   

    $('.allcheckbox').remove(); // Remove checkboxes
    $('#modalDialog').data('checkboxes', []); /* Reset dialog checkbox data */

    /* Add checkboxes from card data */
    $.each($currentTarget.data('checkboxes'), function (i, checkbox) {
        addCheckbox(checkbox.name, checkbox.status);
    });

    $('#modalDialog').dialog({
        modal: true,
        height: 600,
        width: 500,
        position: 'center'
    });
    return false;

});

$("#Getbtn").on("click", function () {

    $currentTarget.data('checkboxes', $('#modalDialog').data('checkboxes')); 
    /* Copy checkbox data to card */

    $('#modalDialog').dialog("close");
});

// Add a new checkBox
$('#btnSaveCheckBox').click(function () {
    addCheckbox($('#checkBoxName').val());
    $('#checkBoxName').val("");
});

function addCheckbox(name, status) {
    status = status || false;

    var container = $('#divboxs');
    var inputs = container.find('input');
    var id = inputs.length + 1;
    var data = {
        status: status,
        name: name
    };

    var div = $('<div />', { class: 'allcheckbox' ,id: 'div_'+ id });
    $('<input />', {
        type: 'checkbox',
        id: 'cb' + id,
        value: name
    }).prop('checked', status).on('change', function () {
        data.status = $(this).prop('checked');
    }).appendTo(div); /* set checkbox status and monitor changes */

    $('<label />', {
        'for': 'cb' + id,
        'div': 'div_' + id,
        text: name
    }).appendTo(div);

    var $editCheckBox = $('<p />', {
        class: 'editCheckBox',
        text: 'Edit'
    }).appendTo(div);

    div.appendTo(container);

    container.data('checkboxes').push(data);
}

    $('#divboxs').on('click', '.editCheckBox', function () {
    var text = $(this).parents(".allcheckbox").find("label").text();
  var id=$(this).parents(".allcheckbox").find("label").attr('div');
    var input = $('<input id="attribute" value="' + text + '" />');

    $('#'+id).html('').append(input);
    input.select();

    input.blur(function () {
        var text = $('#attribute').val();
        $('#attribute').parent().text(text);
        $('#attribute').remove();
    });
});    

});
```